# What's the difference between `Object.prototype.constructor` and `Symbol.species`?

Tags: javascript

From [MDN page for `Object.prototype.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor),

> The `constructor` property returns a reference to the [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) constructor function that created the instance object. Note that the value of this property is a reference to *the function itself*, not a string containing the function's name.

While from [MDN page for `Symbol.species`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species),

> The well-known symbol `Symbol.species` specifies a function-valued property that the constructor function uses to create derived objects.

I know I would almost certainly be wrong, but to me, the descriptions show both of them should always possess the same value.

Why is `Symbol.species` there?

Comment: One is a function, the other is a Symbol.

Comment: @Barmar `Symbol.species` is the key for a getter which returns a class, not another symbol; that’d be like saying that `constructor` is a string, because the key name is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Symbol.species` can control how constructors (classes) create new instances *themselves*. Native classes use this information to determine the behaviour of some of their methods that return new instances (for example, `Array.prototype.map`). This is not about when your code calls the constructor, but when the internals of that class need to produce a new instance in reaction to some method call.

The following example will clarify this difference (hopefully).

Take this very basic (and not efficient) implementation of a priority queue (`PriorityQueue`).  It extends `Array` and overrides its `push` method, so that the pushed value is inserted in its sorted position.

Now, the question is: what should a `PriorityQueue` instance return when you call a non-overridden method on it which is to create a new instance, like `slice`? Should it return a `PriorityQueue` instance or an `Array` instance?

By default, the internals of `Array` will create an instance of the subclass (i.e. a `PriorityQueue` instance). But in some cases you'll want such methods to just return a plain `Array` instance. And that is what you can influence with this symbol. Native classes will take this into account.

Here is the default behaviour:

```js
class PriorityQueue extends Array {
    push(...args) {
        for (let x of args) {
            let i = this.findIndex(a => a > x);
            if (i < 0) i = this.length;
            this.splice(i, 0, x);
        }
    }
}

let q = new PriorityQueue();
q.push(1,5,3,9,6,7,2);
console.log(...q);  // 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9

let pair = q.slice(0, 2);
pair.push(0);
console.log(...pair); // 0, 1, 2 (sorted!)
```

Now let's say you don't want that `pair` slice to behave as a priority queue. Let's say you expected it to be just a normal array. Then you can indicate  that such kinds of methods should return a plain `Array` instance instead of a `PriorityQueue` instance:

```js
class PriorityQueue extends Array {
    // Added:
    static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; }
    push(...args) {
        for (let x of args) {
            let i = this.findIndex(a => a > x);
            if (i < 0) i = this.length;
            this.splice(i, 0, x);
        }
    }
}

let q = new PriorityQueue();
q.push(1,5,3,9,6,7,2);
console.log(...q);  // 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9

let pair = q.slice(0, 2);
pair.push(0);
console.log(...pair); // 1, 2, 0 (normal push behaviour)
```

Comment: Reference in the specification: the [ArraySpeciesCreate](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-arrayspeciescreate) abstract operation. `slice` uses this abstract operation which creates a new `Array` or `PriorityQueue` (or whichever subclass you’re using), based on `Symbol.species`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation @trincot. So does that mean `Object.prototype.constructor` holds information of how the object itself is instantiated, while `Symbol.species` shall dictates how should derived instances from the object be created?

Comment: Indeed, and if the constructor is of your own making, then of course you are responsible of taking the value from `Symbol.species` into account when one of your methods wants to return a "derived" instance. This is not a must. It is just that many native classes do this.